# Can Orion CB subscribes to another Orion CB as context consumer?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Interested in collecting more data in my current research, running fiware application to collect temp and humidity from raspberry pi. I would like to get more data from the city's open Broker.

Is it possible to subscribe the Orion CB from my set-up as context consumer from city's Context Broker(Orion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of connecting one Orion instance with another Orion instance. I'd recommend you to have a look to [Context Broker federation document](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/federation/index.html) for more detail.

Comment: I highly appreciate the url to resource you pointed above. Despite hours of research, I didn't come across it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You can subscribe your Orion instance to whatever context information provider that follows the corresponding API, which includes other Orion instance.

Comment: Subscription format should follow similar to how Orion is subscribed to IoTAgent for notification, if  I am right.